# Why does Python memory usage goes down after while?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Specifically, I recently had to work with a large dataset (~3 GB) and to get a sense of the speed of the loading process (i.e. running `df = pd.read_csv(file)`), I opened a task manager.

As I thought, I saw my Python process' memory usage going constantly up. And around the time when it reached approximately 3 GB, it was fully loaded. Logical.

Then, after doing some other tasks not involving Python, let's say answering emails or browsing online, I noticed the Python memory usage in my task manager was way down, as if I hadn't loading any data yet. But I still had my notebook's kernel running (no interruption there).

Strangely, even after this lowering of memory usage, my code is still functional: I can show information from my dataframe by running for example:

`df.loc[100000:101000,['col1','col2','col3']]`,

which shows these 1000 lines instantly.

Or if I run:

`df.info()`,

which gives me this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3228691 entries, 0 to 3228690
Columns: 117 entries, first_column to last_column
dtypes: category(49), float64(51), object(17)
memory usage: 1.8+ GB
```

Which is strange, because when I run `df.info(memory_usage='deep')` instead of just `df.info()`, then it takes much longer and I can see in my task manager that the Python process' memory usage goes up until it reaches ~1.5 GB. Here is the output then:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3228691 entries, 0 to 3228690
Columns: 117 entries, first_column to last_column
dtypes: category(49), float64(51), object(17)
memory usage: 4.9 GB
```

Again, this is strange because it reaches ~1.5 GB in memory usage, but then the output gives 4.9 GB as memory usage for a file that's ~3 GB.

I guess Python doesn't keep in memory what has not been used for some time, but I'm curious what are the rules here? How does this work? Is this a memory management process from Pandas, or is the the one from Python?

Comment: Without the `deep` option, the memory usage is an estimate, not the real amount of memory. This is reporting virtual memory, not physical RAM, so it has nothing to do with what is kept in memory.

Comment: @Barmar it's not an estimate, rather, it doesn't take into account the memory occupied by references to other pyhton objects in `dtype=object` columns. I don't think it has anything to do with virtual memory, it's a simple equation of itemsize*number_of_items, but when the item type is object, it just uses a machine word (it only takes into account the pointer, not the object being referenced)

Comment: As an aside, assuming your pandas data-frame will require around 3 gigabytes because you are reading a csv file that is around 3 gigabytes is not a good assumption. The way data is represented in a csv (as text, so depending on the encoding, usually around 1 byte per character) is totally different than the way it is represented in main memory (as floating point numbers which take a constant amount of space, and as full-fledged python objects, which require an 8 byte pointer overhead then a hefty python object overhead, and then 1 byte per character for strings)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The documentation specifically says that it's an estimate. I copied it in my answer below.

Comment: My point was that both the estimate and the deep introspection are reporting the amount of virtual memory being used; unprivileged processes generally can't tell which parts of virtual memory are actually in RAM.

Comment: @Barmar sure, it's a minor quibble, but if you look at the [source code and documentation of the method that is called by `.info`, i.e. `.memory_usage`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.0/pandas/core/frame.py#L2561) it explains that the only difference is that `deep=True` changes the way that `object` type columns are calculated (in the context of pandas, this is generally how strings are handled, so it's leaving out the size of the string object and merely reporting the size of having a pointer to an object without `deep=True`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operating system's virtual memory subsystem may page out memory that hasn't been used in a while. Using `memory_usage='deep'` requires Pandas to scan all these objects, so they get paged back in, which causes your process's resident memory usage to increase. That's why this is slow, it has to read lots of information from disk.

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html) explains the difference when using the `deep` option:

> Without deep introspection a memory estimation is made based in column dtype and number of rows assuming values consume the same memory amount for corresponding dtypes. With deep memory introspection, a real memory usage calculation is performed at the cost of computational resources.

With or without this option it's reporting the amount of virtual memory, either estimated or calculated precisely. The increase in memory usage reported in the Task Manager is merely a side effect of the process of calculating the precise amount.